# When I use WsdlImporter I got different data then with Add Web Reference

Tags: wcf

I have to connect to the service provided by the third party client. The issue is to do that dynamically. When I generate proxy on a static way with Add web reference everything is OK. With usage of [WsdlImporter](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter.aspx&ei=pL3AUJf0I4jCswauioHQCw&usg=AFQjCNHH4HA1LbGHqX9cGWCQvJdVPmkJwA) and CodeDom I get some strange generated classes (for proxy client per instance).

Then I saw in case of Add Service Reference I got the same values as with WsdlImporter. My conclusion WsdlImporter is used by svcutil.exe.

Does someone knows what is here so different ?
Service is using SOAP1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem is to use [ServiceDescriptionImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter.aspx). This importer is working as wsdl.exe . 
Additionally, XSD schemes have to be imported (also take care on nested schemas). Great sample for this is on the following :
http://forums.asp.net/post/1740748.aspx

Thank you all, it works now

Answer (score 0):

They're just two different tools. **svcutil.exe** actually uses `WsdlImporter` under the covers (which is why the two outputs are the same). Add Web Reference uses the same classes as the tool **wsdl.exe** (I don't know which class they use internally, but you can use a tool such as ILSpy or reflector to see what wsdl.exe uses.

Answer (score 0):

"Add Web Reference" is part of the legacy ASMX support, not part of WCF. Don't use it if you have a choice.